# Where does 8B/10B "Gigabit Ethernet" come into the picture?

Tags: networking, encoding

I'm reading up on network technology, but there's something that's got me scratching my head. I've read that a popular encoding for sending data across Ethernet is 8B/10B "Gigabit Ethernet".

I've read how the data is packaged up in "frames" which in turn package up "packets" of the data the application needs. Here's where it gets fuzzy. When I write a page of HTML, I set the encoding to Unicode. I understand that that page is packaged in the packet (formatted using the HTTP protocol, etc.)

If the HTML is in Unicode, but the Ethernet encoding is 8B/10B, how do the two encodings coexist? Is the message part of the packet in Unicode while the rest of the frame is 8B/10B?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Reading over this article, http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DataEncapsulationProtocolDataUnitsPDUsandServiceDa.htm, it seems to suggest that the payload at each layer of the OSI model is not re-encoded, but rather new headers/footers are put at the ends around the payload and those are encoded in something new. So, the entire frame is a mix bag of encodings, all sent over the wire together. Anyone that can confirm?

Comment: At each layer, there is an envelope of data that tells that layer how to handle the data.  Imagine giving a friend a large package to take to the post office. That package that contains several individually stamped letters in it that the receiver will then mail.  The large package may be delivered to a different country so that the receiver of it can more easily deliver each of the individual letters that are in envelopes with their own addressees.

Comment: BTW, the 8B/10B is just a way that lower-layer (Ethernet) protocol encodes the octets that it receives.  The receiving Ethernet device will know to reverse that encoding, so that the HTTP/TCP/IP layers never even know that the lower layer used 8B/10B.  For all HTTP knows, you might be using carrier pigeons to deliver the packets.  http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1149.html

Answer (score 1):

They really don't have much to do with each other.  Ethernet is a "lower level" protocol than the HTTP over which your HTML is sent.

The HTML itself is simply data, and Unicode is a way to encoding characters with bits/bytes.

In contrast, Ethernet is a communications protocol for transfering bits/bytes/packets on a link between devices.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Ethernet in the OSI 7 layer model is basically layer 2, the data link layer.  HTTP and your HTML character encoding are the "Data" layers above layer 4 (which is basically TCP).  The abstractions at each layer mean that each layer only has to worry about its job.  The layers of 4 and below are responsible for getting your data from point A to point B.  Ethernet is part of the "getting data from point A to point B" problem.  The layers above that are for figuring what to do with that data.  Your Unicode encoding is a "what to do with that data" question.

Comment: Thanks. I read over the wiki article. I'm still not sure how the data is encoded and sent over the wire though. Is it that parts of the frame are in one encoding and other parts in another? Or does it somehow wrap one encoding inside of another. I'm not sure how that would work? How could it represent the bits in two different ways at the same time?

Comment: HTTP for example wraps up its data into a series of octets (eight bits).  Then it passes those bits to, say TCP, which determines how to break that long stream of octets into packets.  TCP then passes the packets (just chunks of your original octets with an "envelope" of additional data that TCP knows how to handle) to the IP layer, which figures out how to send those (after adding it's own envelope) to the Ethernet layer, which also may add more envelope data, and then eventually to the hardware, which puts electrical signals/transitions on the wires that have meaning as ones or zeros.